# How to recursively make output of a function automatically become input of the same function in R?

Tags: r, function, recursion

I think it is easier to explain my question using a simple example.

```
Name <- c("A1", "A2")
A <- data.frame(Name)

Name <- c("A11", "A12")
A1 <- data.frame(Name)

Name <- c("A21", "A22")
A2 <- data.frame(Name)

crawl_F <- function(x) { 
   return(x[,1])
 }
crawl_F(A)
```

In this example, crawl_F(A) results in A1, A2. However, I want to figure out a way that crawl_F(A) results in A1, A2, A11, A12, A21, A22 with just one call of crawl_F(A). Otherwise, I have to apply the function to A1 and A2 manually in order to get A11, A12, A21, A22.

In the simple case like this, manual apply of the function is not a big deal but if A contains lots of values and each subsequent values has lots of values as well, such manual apply would take enormous time and inefficiency.

I have thought about using recursive function but have not figured out how to write recursion for this probelm. Any ideas with or without using recursion to solve this problem?

Comment: This is potentially going into an infinite loop. what's your termination condition? I'm assuming it's not just these three, and you have more dataframes like `A21` , `A22` and so on.

Answer (score -1):

for the given example u can get ur desired output vector like this:

```
crall <- apply(do.call(rbind, list(A, A1, A2)), 1, function(x) { append(crall, x) })
```

combine all dfs in a single df by calling rbind with do.call, thanks for the hint @Roland.
the apply function iterates the df rowwise (sec. arg = 1) and appends each row to `crall`. hope this kinda what u were looking for

Comment: Use `do.call(rbind, list(A, A1, A2))` to combine the data.frames. Your solution is extremely inefficient and a horror of unnecessary side effects.

Comment: I asked the original questions. Thanks for your ideas. I think I need to clarify my question a bit more. My question originally arises from web crawling. 
Let's say that A is a certain webpage. If I run a function called crawl_F(x), for example, the function spits out links that were found on A, which would be A1 and A2 in this case. Running crawl_F(x) against A1 and A2 would spit out their respective links that can be found on each of A1 and A2, which would be (A11 and A12), (A21 and A22). The issue here is that when you run the function against A, you don't know what links will be resulted

Comment: In other words, you don't know A1,A2,A11,A12,A21,A22 in advance. I want to find all links on A, and links on resulting links of A, links on results of results, and so on... So my original intent of question is to know how to get  ALL such links by calling crawl_F(A). Does this make sense?